# Get height of hidden dynamic view

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view

I have two views, one under another. The `firstView` is shown, the `secondView` is hidden. Pressing a button, one will collapse, then second will expand. The problem is the `secondView` builds dynamicaly: it has height calculation in `onMeasure` ([tag cloud](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout), wrapping tags to new lines, as a result height of view changed).

So I can get height of tag cloud container view as a single-line child views, with no calculation of height, using the code below. But how can I get real height of `secondView` before it shown?

```
view.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
int height = view.getMeasuredHeight();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ViewTreeObserver to wait for the view to be laid out then get the height and width.

```
int height;
int width
secondView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            height = secondView.getHeight();
            width = secondView.getWidth();
            secondView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Not sure this callback is going be called when the `view` is hidden

Comment: Not when it's hidden but when it becomes visible it will be

Comment: The `view` initially hidden and should become visible only through animation

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is following:

- Wrap the `view` that should be expanded to `RelativeLayout`
- Set the `view` visible, but hidden by removing it off-screen: set `layout_marginTop="-1000dp"`
- Then you can get real height of the `view` in code (see below) by waiting until it become visible

Snippet:

```
    view.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    viewHeight = view.getHeight(); // getting real height, use further for animation
                    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    clearLayoutMargins(view); // clear margins here
                }
            });
```